# Meteor on Rails integration within MVVM model

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mvvm, meteor

Is there any experience of Rails/[Meteor](http://meteor.com) integration ?

I've the idea of smoothly integrate (add) small and light micro-apps, based on the pre-existing Rails/MongoDB application altready in place.

At the moment [Meteor](http://meteor.com) is pretty new, but fast rising ... the only examples arountd seems to be on just a side of MV*, what about having a backend MVC on Rails and a client-side MVC on JS Meteor ?

Any Experience ?

UPDATE

I know Meteor "[vision](http://meteor.com/about/mission)" but I've an app entirely written on Rails/MongoID already in place. Instead of trash away everithing and restarting from scratch, I'd like to add small pieces of new appication/functionality one at a time, in a distribuited web services stile. For example, while I have http://examplesite.com/trends on Rails I thought to start developing http://examplesite.com/categories on Meteor but Meteor should be able to call existing MongoID rails models to get the data crunched ... so I'm looking for the best way to integrate Meteor with Rails/MongoID at last to pick up the data.

What's the best way of doing that ?

Comment: Why would you want to mix technologies when you have things working on rails?  That's just silly if you don't have a true business need.. and I can't think of a single business reason to use Meteor at this point.

Comment: @Shane: mainly to improve reactivity, implementing powerful data synchronization and latency compensation, in a way that Rails/AJAX cannot do currently, because are builded on top of old http client/server model, while here, you are on realtime web by default. All layers, from database to template, should make an event-driven interface available. This is an attempt to implement a new paradigm in web programming, something we are all looking for (see IlyaGrigorik:http://www.igvita.com/2012/01/18/building-a-modern-web-stack-for-the-realtime-web) Se also http://docs.meteor.com/#sevenprinciples

Comment: Yet another interesting question shot down because it was posed badly. Rather than closing it, why not edit it so that it works better as a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Backbone.js](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone), it has controllers and can be used inside Meteor.

Other than that, Meteor isn't meant to contact a back-end Rails; while it's possible, it would completely defeat the purpose of what Meteor was meant for. Other than that, there are enough tutorials available.

Comment: Thanks for answering Tom, please see the UPDATE on main Q.